# how to get input email and send in php

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I want to get an email address as input by the user and send an email to them using PHPMailer.

** My HTML code and PHP code**

```html
<html>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="Emails.php">
        Email address <input type="email" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" required=""><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Emails.php**

```php
$_POST["emailaddress"] = "";
$emailaddress = ($_POST["emailaddress"]);

require 'C:\xampp\composer\vendor\autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\ PHPMailer\ PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\ PHPMailer\ Exception;
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'my email address'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'my passsword'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail-> Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('my email address', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('$emailaddress', 'Dear User'); // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'This is your password';
$mail->Body = 'Enter this as your password';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: '.$mail - > ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

So I use this HTML and PHP code and get an error as

```
Invalid address: (to): $emailaddress The message could not be sent. Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address
```

My PHP version is 5.512.  So could you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The [contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) does exactly what you ask.

Comment: Thanks  Synchro , it's very helpful  for me.